# Kendo grid - Adding a combobox and a icon to the same column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-combobox

If you have a kendo grid, is it possible to have a combobox and an icon in the same column? Basically using an editor and a command? Or the other question is to use an editor for a command column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an editor function that is something like this:

```
editor: function (container, options) {
    // Add icon
    $('<span class="k-icon k-add"></span>').appendTo(container);
    // Add container for the combobox
    var span = $('<span></span>').appendTo(container);
    // Define the combobox
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '"></input>')
            .appendTo(span)
            .kendoComboBox({
                dataSource: [ "Seatle", "Madrid", "Sofia", "Palo Alto" ]
            });
}
```

It might be done more compact but here I try to make clear the different steps instead of chaining more functions.

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ehnSq/12/ Try editing `City`

Comment: The only issue I am having with that now is I can't seem to assign a click event to it. I've tried specifying the onClick Attribute in the tag, and I've tried searching and attaching it via jquery. Instead of a span, i used a input of type image.

Comment: Could you update my fiddle with what you have? So I can take a look into what you have. Thanks!

Comment: Here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/ehnSq/13/  I didn't add the click attribute because i have to specify a namespace. But I also tried attaching the click event on the databound, but since the image is hidden it won't bind, I think i need to bind the click event in my editor.

Comment: That did, it adding the following in the editor allowed me to hook into the click event:
$(".k-icon-addcustomer").on("click", function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
            context.addCustomer(dataItem);

        });

Comment: Thanks for all your help and quick response.

Comment: Hi, it seems this works great for IE and FireFox, would you happen to know why this wouldn't work on Chrome? I get the image in chrome just fine, but the click is not fired.

Comment: I actually used chrome for testing [it](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ehnSq/12/). What means "don't work" in Chrome, what is not working?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add, so I get the image to show up. But the click event is firing just fine in Firefox and IE, but not in chrome.

Comment: i've update the jsfiddle to show exactly what I did. http://jsfiddle.net/ehnSq/15/ The binding of the click event works in IE and firefox, but notice in Chrome it closes the Column out.

Comment: Hi OnaBai, Just wanted to let you know what was happening. I figured it out. If I have the comobobox before the image, the blur event on the combobox was preventing the click event on the image in Chrome. So by binding a blur event and stopping the propagation of it, it resolved the issue. Just thought you would like to know.